# Is it possible to receive notification of an end of call while not in the foreground but have a UIBackgroundMode?

Tags: ios

If my app has a UIBackgroundMode (location) and is not currently in the foreground when a phone call occurs/ends, is it possible for my app to know the phone call has ended and perform some activity still while in the background?